# Planted coriander roots which grew well for a week & now started dying

Tags: houseplants, roots, cilantro

I have planted a dozen coriander roots last weekend. They grew out from the soil, nice and green for the 1st few days. But a week later they have now stopped growing. They seem to be dying honestly.
I have watered them daily and managed to keep them in medium sunlight though it is rainy season. Unable to figure why they have stopped growing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its likely the sun exposure - these are tiny seedlings, not small plants at this stage, and they are not strong enough to tolerate sunlight. It would have been best to pot them up individually in small pots until they did develop into bushy, small plants at least six inches tall, with a well formed root system, and then transfer them to this large pot, if that's where you want them to grow. It can be difficult for tiny seedlings to grow properly in so much soil in a pot - they will not form good solid  rootballs, rather, they will produce long, weak and wandering roots in all that soil.